# VPN and Bonjour conflicting

Tags: vpn, bonjour

Does anyone know why a VPN connection might interfere with Apple's [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29)? I've noticed that my Mac and various iDevices have trouble finding each other on my local network, when I have VPN connections open. Things like Home Sharing and Wi-Fi Sync work some of the time, but sometimes fail to find the other device.

The VPN connections are made using [IPSecuritas](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/), which is a GUI around raccoon. I have the local "endpoint mode" set to Host.

Apple mentions that Home Sharing [may conflict with VPNs](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2972), but they don't specify why, or how to fix it.

I'm using a Mac with OS 10.7.3 and IPSecuritas to connect to the VPN, an iPhone, and an iPad.

Comment: What does your routing table look like, before and after?

Comment: How would I find that?

Comment: Run `netstat -rn`. Obscure any sensitive addresses.

Comment: If I do that before and after connecting to the VPN, the results are the same, other than some of the numbers under "Refs", "Use", and "Expire". Here's the result: http://pastebin.com/QZUYUFYz